# Wondering why my Ocean Spider Plant is not thriving

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, indoors, leaves

A friend of mines had given me this Ocean Plant about six months ago. It has not made the long spider babies that normally come out. I was wondering if someone can suggest what Im doing wrong or if this is the wrong plant that has the spider babies.

[image]

[image: no]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never heard this called Ocean plant before, the usual common name is spider plant, though its botanical name is Chlorophytum comosum. The 'spider babies' are formed after flowering - yours just hasn't produced any yet, but may do so in the next few months as the plant matures a bit. They do best in bright daylight (not direct sun) so ensure your plant is getting enough light to encourage formation of offspring.

I am wondering if there is a drainage hole in its pot; if there isn't, find a pot which does have drainage holes instead. Allow to dry out a bit between waterings - when the surface of the soil feels just about dry to the touch, then water well and allow excess to drain away freely. Further info https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/spider-plant/spider-plant-care-gardening-tips-for-spider-plants.htm

Comment: From the leaf colouring, it looks like it is getting enough light. The white stripes on the leaves tend to go green in low light conditions. They tend to flower in early summer, and flower better when they are a bit pot bound. If you got the plant 6 months ago, you might have just missed on last year's crop of babies, or the plant was too small back then.